# Writing an extra semicolon in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php code where I am generating javascript using php

```
function FunJavaScriptRedirection($url)
{
echo "<script>";
echo "var x = ";
echo  $url';';
echo "window.open(x)";
echo "</script>";
}
```

My problem is I want semicolon after storing value to variable x .I dont know how to do that I am  getting javascript error please help me out .

Comment: You should be getting a PHP syntax error. Turn on error reporting: `error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: it does not mean y should mark as negative vote i just asked my question

Comment: The downvotes are because a syntax error shows very little attempt to solve your own problem. Turn on error reporting and you'll be able to help yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when you get the concatenation right, your code will still not do what you want as you are outputting "x" I stead of the value of the variable.

So after fixing the concatenation

```
echo $url . ';';
```

You need to change the following line:

```
echo 'window.open(' . x . ');';
```

And I suspect you should declare the language used inside the script tag...

Comment: You are confusing PHP & Javascript.
x is a Javascript variable, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo  $url';';
```

to

```
echo  $url . ';';
```

See [Contactenation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_string.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a point between $url and ';'.